# Reusing multiple attributes in an Ansible playbook from "template"

Tags: ansible

Given the following Ansible playbook:

```yaml
- name: Configure Keycloak
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    auth_keycloak_url: http://localhost:8080/auth
    auth_realm: master
    auth_username: admin
    auth_client_id: admin-cli
    realm: myrealm
  vars_prompt:
    - name: auth_password
      prompt: Please enter Keycloak admin password
  tasks:
    - name: Configure client roles
      community.general.keycloak_role:
        auth_keycloak_url: "{{ auth_keycloak_url }}"
        auth_realm: "{{ auth_realm }}"
        auth_username: "{{ auth_username }}"
        auth_password: "{{ auth_password }}"
        auth_client_id: "{{ auth_client_id }}"
        realm: "{{ realm }}"
        name: "{{ item }}"
        client_id: my-client
        state: present
      loop:
        - role_1
        - role_2
        - role_3
```

When adding more tasks for Keycloak, I would need to repeat the `auth_` attributes for each task.

Does Ansible provide a way to define multiple attributes as a "variable"? Something like this (pseudo code):

```yaml
- name: Configure Keycloak
  hosts: localhost
  # something like a "template"
  template:
    keycloak_auth_template:
      auth_keycloak_url: http://localhost:8080/auth
      auth_realm: master
      auth_username: admin
      auth_client_id: admin-cli
      realm: myrealm
  vars_prompt:
    - name: auth_password
      prompt: Please enter Keycloak admin password
  tasks:
    - name: Configure client roles
      community.general.keycloak_role:
        # "insert the template"
        insert_template: keycloak_auth_template
        name: "{{ item }}"
        client_id: my-client
        state: present
      loop:
        - role_1
        - role_2
        - role_3
```